# Why difference in number of user displayed in "jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time"

Tags: jmeter

Can any one explain the below difference about the number of user displayed in "jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time"

Case 1:

```
Thread Group details: 
Number of Users: 100
Ramp-Up period: 100
Loop Count: 1
```

Here active user count display in "jp@gc - Active Threads Over Time" are one user.
[image]

Case 2:

```
 Thread Group: 
 Number of Users: 100
 Ramp-Up period: 100
 Loop Count: Infinite
 Specify Thread Life Time: 100
```

Here user keeps adding in every seconds.
[image]

Comment: This is because of the duration of your tests. Follow the answer to this thread: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7902/what-is-the-concurrent-users-in-load-testing-using-jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case you have loop count set in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to 1 which means that each JMeter thread (virtual user) will execute all the [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the Thread Group **only once**.

It looks like you have only 1 sampler or all the Samplers response time is less than one second therefore current user ends before next one starts.

Just add more loops and you will see more concurrency.

More information: [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected)

Answer (score 0):

In first case each thread is executed once and because ramp period equal to thread number each thread will start after each second, assuming thread ends each second, there will be only 1 active thread each second

Second case threads will loop endlessly so each second another thread will join previous threads